# Create dynamically table with 3 columns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have array of objects:

```
var arr = [{id:1, name:Mike },{id:2, name:Tom},{id:3, name:Herman},
           {id:4, name:Ursula},{id:5, name:Sam},{id:6, name:Jenny},
           {id:7, name:Helga},{id:8, name:Nikolas},{id:9, name:Surgen},
           {id:10, name:Jorg}]
```

I need to generate dynamically table that display items in array above.
The table should contain 3 columns and rows according to the numbers of items in array.

For example, for arr above I want my table to be:

```
<div id="here_table">
    <table>
          <tr><td>Mike</td><td>Tom</td><td>Herman</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Ursula</td><td>Sam</td><td>Jenny</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Helga</td><td>Nikolas</td><td>Surgen</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Jorg</td><td>Empty</td><td>Empty</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Or if my array is:

```
var arr = [{id:1, name:Mike },{id:2, name:Sam},{id:3, name:Herman},
           {id:10, name:Jorg},{id:2, name:Tom}] ;
```

The table is:

```
<div id="here_table">
    <table>
          <tr><td>Mike</td><td>Sam</td><td>Herman</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Jorg</td><td>Tom</td><td>Empty</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

How can I implement tables that has 3 columns and and rows according to the numbers of items in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the amount of empty cells by dividing the array `length` by 3, rounding up, and subtracting the `length`.

Iterate the array using a `for` loop up to the `length` of the array + the empty cells amount, and add a new `<tr>` whenever the index % 3 equals 0 (the index is divisible by 3).

```js
var arr = [{"id":1,"name":"Mike"},{"id":2,"name":"Tom"},{"id":3,"name":"Herman"},{"id":4,"name":"Ursula"},{"id":5,"name":"Sam"},{"id":6,"name":"Jenny"},{"id":7,"name":"Helga"},{"id":8,"name":"Nikolas"},{"id":9,"name":"Surgen"},{"id":10,"name":"Jorg"}];
           
var table = $('<table>');
var tr;
var empty = Math.ceil(arr.length / 3) * 3 - arr.length;
  
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length + empty; i++) {
  i % 3 === 0 && (tr = $('<tr>').appendTo(table));
  
  tr.append('<td>' + (i < arr.length ? arr[i].name : 'empty') + '</td>');
}

$('#here_table').append(table);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="here_table"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use modulus operator `%`

```js
var arr = [{id:1, name:"Mike" },{id:2, name:"Tom"},{id:3, name:"Herman"},
           {id:4, name:"Ursula"},{id:5, name:"Sam"},{id:6, name:"Jenny"},
           {id:7, name:"Helga"},{id:8, name:"Nikolas"},{id:9, name:"Surgen"},
           {id:10, name:"Jorg"}];
var str =  "<table>";
for(var i in arr){
  if(i%3==0)
    str +=  "<tr>";
  str +=  "<td>"+arr[i].name+"</td>";
  if((i+1)%3==0)
    str +=  "</tr>";  
  
}
str +=  "</table>";
document.querySelector("#here_table").innerHTML = str;
```

```css
tr td{
  width:10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="here_table">
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a **JavaScript function** to create that table

**Here, I'm using jQuery library to append the element but you can also use JavaScript directly to add the element.**

```js
// Object Array
var arr = [
    { id: 1, name: "Mike" },
    { id: 2, name: "Tom" },
    { id: 3, name: "Herman" },
    { id: 4, name: "Ursula" },
    { id: 5, name: "Sam" },
    { id: 6, name: "Jenny" },
    { id: 7, name: "Helga" },
    { id: 8, name: "Nikolas" },
    { id: 9, name: "Surgen" },
    { id: 10, name: "Jorg" }
];

// Generating the table creation HTML code
function createTable(array) {
  var tableString = "<table border='1'><tr>";
  var numOfCells = Math.ceil(arr.length / 3)*3;
  for (var i = 0; i < numOfCells; i++) {
    if (array[i]) {
      tableString += "<td>" + array[i].name + "</td>";
    } else {
      tableString += "<td>Empty</td>";
    }
    if ((i + 1) % 3 === 0) {
      tableString += "</tr><tr>";
    }
  }
  tableString += "</tr></table>";
  return tableString;
}

// Appending that DOM element to the div 'here_table'
$('#here_table').append(createTable(arr));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=here_table></div>
```